# Extract single datapoint from netCDF file in R using ndcf

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm trying to extract a single variable from a 3-dimensional netCDF file.

```
[1] "file blah.nc has 3 dimensions:"
[1] "longitude   Size: 200"
[1] "latitude   Size: 100"
[1] "time   Size: 2000"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file blah.nc has 1 variables:"
[1] "short temp[longitude,latitude,time]  Longname:temperature Missval:-9999"
```

Time's units are "days". I just want to get a single day in the middle of the dataset at `time=t1` say. The [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ncdf/ncdf.pdf) seems to indicate that I should `temp1 = get.var.ncdf(blah.nc, "temp", start=c(long1, lat1, t1))`, but this gets all temperatures for all longs and lats until the ends of the arrays. I don't want to read the entire variable and then extract the desired value in R, I want the ncdf library to do it. `get.var.ncdf` doesn't take a `end=c(long1+1, lat1+1, t1+1)` argument as far as I can tell? So, how can I do this using ncdf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `count` argument:

```
temp1 = get.var.ncdf(blah.nc, "temp", start=c(long1, lat1, t1), count=c(2,2,2))
```